# How to open a file with "|" in the name from python3 function?

Tags: vimscript-python

A file with `|` in the name confuses vim.

Example file:

```
/tmp/Testchars/UTF8 Grin ||..
```

The plugin tries to run:

```
vim.command(f"edit {chosen_file}")
```

But Vim interprets the `|` as a filter:

```
vim.error: Vim:E492: Not an editor command: |...
```

How to escape not only this, but *all other special characters that could confuse vim (like +)*?  I don't want this to keep happening.

Context: I am the author of a file selector UX called [ViLark](https://github.com/kjpgit/vilark).

Comment: That would be a Python question.

Comment: No, it's not.  It's a question on what are the entire set of magic chars for vim :edit, or if there's a non-magic edit command I can call.

Comment: Yes, it is. The Vim part of your "file selector UX" is written in Python (and you boast about not wanting to use vimscript in public forums) so it is strictly a Python problem… and a very simple one at that. "What are the special characters one has to be aware of when using `:edit` programmatically?" would be a very different, much more relevant question… anyway, see `:help cmdline-special` and follow the link to `:help fnameescape()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Vim way to do this would be something like

```
:execute 'edit' fnameescape(chosen_file)
```

From `if_pyth` where you have `chosen_file` as a string, you could try

```python
escaped_file = vim.eval(f'fnameescape({repr(chosen_file)})')
```

But since Python's `repr` and Vim's strings aren't quite the same, this may still backfire. Unfortunately, I don't think you can use `vim.eval('fnameescape')` to get a function reference in Python world. So maybe you're better off with the following hack:

```
" vim
command -nargs=1 MyPluginEdit execute 'edit' fnameescape(<f-args>)

# python
vim.command(f'MyPluginEdit {chosen_file}')
```

Comment: You can't have _ in a command name, but otherwise this works perfectly for me.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @KP99 oh, good point. I'll edit the `_` out. A function might be cleaner for the user's "namespace" of stuff, but then you still have string-escape problems, so I think I'll keep a command

Answer (score 0):

I would escape with a backslash (`\`):

```
/tmp/Testchars/UTF8 Grin \|\|
```

Or in your code:

```python
vim.command(f"edit {chosen_file}".replace("|", r"\|")
```

Comment: That does indeed solve this particular file, but what about other chars like "+", or other potential land mines I haven't stumbled upon?

Comment: fnameescape()! @KP99 (it’s a Vim function, but you probably have access to it if you’re using the if_python api)